# Removing data from Cloud Firestore using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a simple React app that uses Cloud Firestore for user auth and storing data; something that I could serve using heroku or something like that.

I'm running into trouble with enabling a user to delete their account (and associated data), as Firestore tells me that it's a bad idea to delete collections from the client side. Here's what they say:

> Deleting a collection requires coordinating an unbounded number of individual delete requests. If you need to delete entire collections, do so only from a trusted server environment. While it is possible to delete a collection from a mobile/web client, doing so has negative security and performance implications.https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

While I might be able to delete the document connected with the user's account, this suggests that I can't really delete the sub-collections under that document.

So what would be a good way of automatically removing both the user document and user sub-collections? Can I achieve this through my react code? If not, is there a relatively easy way to do it without building a fancy back end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the documentation never says that this is not possible, just not recommended.

This makes sense if you consider that if you want to delete everything, including documents from subcollection, you would have to create a logic that will do this one by one, which is a very read intensive process and all of this data processing happening in your webapp is not a good practice, it might slow your app down or even block functionality while this process is occuring, etc.

What I would recommend for you is to follow the recommendations of Firestore itself, which is to create a Callable Function that will perform this actions for you, all processing will be done by that function and this will not degrade your app performance, you can find more details in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#solution_delete_data_with_a_callable_cloud_function).